# Python super method and calling alternatives

Tags: python, class, super

I see everywhere examples that super-class methods should be called by:

```
super(SuperClass, instance).method(args)
```

Is there any disadvantage to doing:

```
SuperClass.method(instance, args)
```

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Consider the following situation:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Running A.__init__')
        super(A,self).__init__()
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Running B.__init__')        
        # super(B,self).__init__()
        A.__init__(self) 

class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Running C.__init__')
        super(C,self).__init__()
class D(B,C):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Running D.__init__')
        super(D,self).__init__()

foo=D()
```

So the classes form a so-called inheritance diamond:

```
    A
   / \
  B   C
   \ /
    D
```

Running the code yields

```
Running D.__init__
Running B.__init__
Running A.__init__
```

That's bad because `C`'s `__init__` is skipped. The reason for that is  because `B`'s `__init__` calls `A`'s `__init__` directly.

**The purpose of `super` is to resolve inheritance diamonds**. If you un-comment

```
# super(B,self).__init__()
```

and comment-out

```
A.__init__(self)
```

the code yields the more desireable result:

```
Running D.__init__
Running B.__init__
Running C.__init__
Running A.__init__
```

Now all the `__init__` methods get called. Notice that at the time you define `B.__init__` you might *think* that `super(B,self).__init__()` is the same as calling `A.__init__(self)`, but you'd be wrong. In the above situation, `super(B,self).__init__()` actually calls `C.__init__(self)`.

Holy smokes,   `B` knows nothing about `C`, and yet `super(B,self)` knows to call `C`'s `__init__`? The reason is because `self.__class__.mro()` contains `C`. In other words, `self` (or in the above, `foo`) knows about `C`.

So be careful -- the two are not fungible. They can yield vastly different results.

Using `super` [has pitfalls.](http://fuhm.org/super-harmful/) It takes a considerable level of coordination between all the classes in the inheritance diagram. (They must, for example, either have the same call signature for `__init__`, since any particular `__init__` would not know which other `__init__` `super` might call next, or 
else [use `**kwargs`](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).) Furthermore, you must be consistent about using `super` everywhere. Skip it once (as in the above example) and you defeat the entire purpose of `super`.
See the link for more pitfalls.

If you have full control over your class hierarchy, or you avoid inheritance diamonds, then there is no need for `super`.

Comment: +1 for the super-harmful link.  I was about to post it myself.

Comment: [Python's super() considered super!](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) shows why and how to use `super()`. btw, with new-style classes and multiple inheritance there is always an inheritance diamond  due to common `object` parent.

Comment: +1 for "(They must, for example, all have the same call signature for __init__, since any particular __init__ does not know which other __init__ super might call next.)". As I see it, this signature coordination puts the "harmful" in super() ... of course one can have something like __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) but if you can externalize your method/constructor meaning via its very signature why making it  obscure ?

Comment: But since the call signature of object.__ini___ is no arguments, then none of the inits can have multiple arguments. You can't as far as I can see use the *args, **kwargs method because at some point A is called and it calls object.__init__ with arguments and everything goes wrong. Or am I missing something (I surely am)? I can't find good examples which use __init__'s with arguments.

Comment: @FrancisDavey: You can have a base class which does not call `super`, and/or you have to rely on the subclasses reducing `args` and `kwargs` so as to be empty by the time `object.__init__` is called. See [Raymond Hettinger's article](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) for a great exposition including examples.

Comment: Thanks. What it turns out is that I have a diamond A, B, C, D which ought to be just like this but for some reason only D, B and A are being called. C doesn't get a look in and I can't work out why. That is the more fundamental problem rather than the problem I thought was there. Are there any examples with more complex use of __init__ that pass arguments around a diamond? That would be useful.

Comment: Yes, there are examples in the article I linked to above. (Note the use of mandatory positional arguments, followed by `**kwargs`. The mandatory arguments are removed from `kwargs` when you call `super(...).__init__(**kwargs)`. So each time you call `super` the `kwargs` is getting smaller....)

Comment: Thanks. That is very helpful and has helped me put together a working diamond multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 9):

There's no penalty as-is, though your example is somewhat misguided.  In the first example, it should be

```
super(SubClass, instance).method(args)  # Sub, not SuperClass
```

and that leads me to quote the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super):

> There are two typical use cases for `super`. In a class hierarchy with single inheritance, `super` can be used to refer to parent classes without naming them explicitly, thus making the code more maintainable. This use closely parallels the use of `super` in other programming languages.
>
> The second use case is to support cooperative multiple inheritance in a dynamic execution environment. This use case is unique to Python and is not found in statically compiled languages or languages that only support single inheritance. This makes it possible to implement “diamond diagrams” where multiple base classes implement the same method. Good design dictates that this method have the same calling signature in every case (because the order of calls is determined at runtime, because that order adapts to changes in the class hierarchy, and because that order can include sibling classes that are unknown prior to runtime).

Basically, by using the first method you don't have to hard-code your parent class in there for single-class hierarchies, and you simply can't really do what you want (efficiently/effectively) using the second method when using multiple inheritance.

Comment: Do I understand it right, there are no cons to using `super` in single inheritance situations?