# Python multi-inheritance, __init__

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, init, super

Regarding multiple parent inheritance, when I call the `super`.`__init__`, why doesn't parent2's `__init__` function get called? Thanks.

```
class parent(object):
    var1=1
    var2=2
    def __init__(self,x=1,y=2):
        self.var1=x
        self.var2=y

class parent2(object):
    var4=11
    var5=12
    def __init__(self,x=3,y=4):
        self.var4=x
        self.var5=y

    def parprint(self):
        print self.var4
        print self.var5

class child(parent, parent2):
    var3=5
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        super(child, self).__init__(x,y)

childobject = child(9,10)
print childobject.var1
print childobject.var2
print childobject.var3
childobject.parprint()
```

Output is

```
9
10
5
11
12
```

Comment: Side note: http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/ explains `super` quite well and shows how it can play nice with multiple inheritance.

Comment: PleaseCapitalizeClassNames

Answer (score 27):

If you want to use `super` in `child` to call `parent.__init__` and `parent2._init__`, then both parent `__init__`s must also call `super`:

```
class parent(Base):
    def __init__(self,x=1,y=2):
        super(parent,self).__init__(x,y)   

class parent2(Base):
    def __init__(self,x=3,y=4):
        super(parent2,self).__init__(x,y)
```

See ["Python super method and calling alternatives"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5033903/190597) for more details on the sequence of calls to `__init__` caused by using `super`.

---

```
class Base(object): 
    def __init__(self,*args):
        pass

class parent(Base):
    var1=1
    var2=2
    def __init__(self,x=1,y=2):
        super(parent,self).__init__(x,y)        
        self.var1=x
        self.var2=y

class parent2(Base):
    var4=11
    var5=12
    def __init__(self,x=3,y=4):
        super(parent2,self).__init__(x,y)
        self.var4=x
        self.var5=y

    def parprint(self):
        print self.var4
        print self.var5

class child(parent, parent2):
    var3=5
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        super(child, self).__init__(x,y)


childobject = child(9,10)
print childobject.var1
print childobject.var2
print childobject.var3
childobject.parprint()
```

---

You might be wondering, "Why use `Base`?". If `parent` and `parent2` had inherited directly from `object`, then 
`super(parent2,self).__init__(x,y)` would call `object.__init__(x,y)`. That raises a `TypeError` since `object.__init__()` takes no parameters.

To workaround this issue, you can make a class `Base` which accepts arguments to `__init__` but does not pass them on to `object.__init__`. With `parent` and `parent2` inheriting from `Base`, you avoid the `TypeError`.

Answer (score 10):

Because `parent` is next in [method resolution order (MRO)](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/), and it never uses `super()` to call into `parent2`.

Comment: thanks, but for parent, it's superclass is object? how would it call into parent2?

Comment: MRO doesn't care what the current superclass is when MI is involved.

Answer (score 6):

See this example:

```
class Base(object): 
    def __init__(self, c):
        print('Base called by {0}'.format(c))
        super().__init__()

class ParentA(Base):
    def __init__(self, c):
        print('ParentA called by {0}'.format(c))
        super().__init__('ParentA')

class ParentB(Base):
    def __init__(self, c):
        print('ParentB called by {0}'.format(c))
        super().__init__('ParentB')

class Child(ParentA, ParentB):
    def __init__(self, c):
        print('Child called by {0}'.format(c))
        super().__init__('Child')

Child('Construct')
print(Child.mro())
```

This will output:

```
Child called by Construct
ParentA called by Child
ParentB called by ParentA
Base called by ParentB
[<class '__main__.Child'>, <class '__main__.ParentA'>, <class '__main__.ParentB'>, <class '__main__.Base'>, <class 'object'>]
```

Python multiple inheritance is like a chain, in `Child` class `mro`, the `super` class of `ParentA` is `ParentB`, so you need call `super().__init__()` in `ParentA` to init `ParentB`.

If you change `super().__init__('ParentA')` to `Base.__init__(self, 'ParentA')`, this will break the inheritance chain, output:

```
Child called by Construct
ParentA called by Child
Base called by ParentA
[<class '__main__.Child'>, <class '__main__.ParentA'>, <class '__main__.ParentB'>, <class '__main__.Base'>, <class 'object'>]
```

### More info about [MRO](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/)

Comment: You should point out that your example is for Python 3. super() without arguments will fail in Python 2.