# Python 2.7 Initialize multiple inheritors

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, inheritance, initialization

I am trying to to run the following piece of code, and I want `C` to initialize both `A` and `B` (and possible more) in a neat and dynamic manner.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Class A init'

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Class B init'

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        super(C, self).__init__()
        print 'Class C init'

c = C()
```

However, this only outputs

```
 Class A init
 Class C init
```

I know that this is due to the depth-first search manner when invoking super(...), and it stops when first method was found. Can I in some way initialize all super classes?

**Edit:**
Defining `C` as below achieves the goal of initializing all super classes. Is there a way to implicit initialize all super classes?

```
class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)
        B.__init__(self)
        print 'Class C init'
```

**Solution:** As pointed out a `super(B, self).__init__()` was added in class `B`

Comment: Why don't you call `super(B, self).__init__()` in `B` ? Can't think of a design where you really would want `C` to do both...

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8688114/3004881

Comment: `B` does not inherit `A`

Comment: @JonClements: I stand corrected. That worked. I did not know that.

Comment: This is a pretty bad way of inheriting. Why not just use a mixin for the behavior that you do want?