# Subclassing two classes in Python?

Tags: python

I have the following class inheritance in Python:

```
A
|
B--D
|  |
C  E
```

What bothers me is that I have a lot of duplicate class methods in C and E. This can be avoided if I make E a child of C instead of D, but then I'd have to duplicate D's methods in E.

Is there a way for E to subclass both D and C so that E has functions from both C and D?

Comment: `class E(C,D):...`?

Comment: Yes, Python allows multiple inheritance.

Comment: or move shared code into another class and derive both from that

Comment: @wwii oh would that work? In that case, what would `super().__init__()` be? C's or D's?

Comment: @SibbsGambling search for MRO, i.e method resolution order

Comment: If you are using `super`, *every* class should use `super`. The order in which each individual class's `__init__` method is called depends on the final method resolution order.

Comment: [https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance) ... [https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/)

Comment: Using wii's suggestion, the method resolution order would be E, C, B, D, A, object. Note that this means that `D.__init__` would be called from `B.__init__`, even though `B` does not inherit from D. `super` is a somewhat misnamed class.

Comment: [The Art of Subclassing](https://pyvideo.org/europython-2011/the-art-of-subclassing-0.html) - EuroPython Pyvideo - I think there are also videos of this talk at other venues.

Comment: Or maybe I meant [Python’s super() considered super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).  Related:[Python multi-inheritance, __init__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688114/python-multi-inheritance-init) ... [Calling parent class __init__ with multiple inheritance, what's the right way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575409/calling-parent-class-init-with-multiple-inheritance-whats-the-right-way).

Comment: Does [How does Python's super() work with multiple inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance) answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inherit from two classes at once:

```
class a(b, c):
    pass
```

So, if in b, thing1 = 123 and in c, thing2 = 64, a would have both of those variables.

```
>>> a.thing1
123
>>> a.thing2
64
```

But if class a is like this:

```
class a(b, c):
    thing3 = 42
```

Using `dir(a)`, in the end of the huge list would appear:

```
'thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3'
```

Therefore, you can do this:

```
>>> a.thing3
42
```

But not this (I assume):

```
>>> c.thing3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make **multiple inheritance**. You have a lot of posibilities when you implement this, so it depends on your needs.

For example:

```
class E(C, D):
   pass
```

Check this out:
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/multiple-inheritance

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly. Check out this resource [https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/multiple-inheritance/#:~:text=In%20Python%20a%20class%20can,concept%20from%20object%20orientated%20programming](https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/multiple-inheritance/#:%7E:text=In%20Python%20a%20class%20can,concept%20from%20object%20orientated%20programming).

```
class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

class C(B):
    pass

class D(B):
    pass

class E(C, D):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass multiple classes as follows

```
class C:
   pass
class D:
   pass
class E(C, D):
   pass
```

You may even create a mixin (which is just a class that's not meant to be used standalone) and put the common features there, and add that mixin to your classes that need those features.

[What is a mixin, and why are they useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-are-they-useful)

Answer (score 1):

One of solutions is to extract methods duplicated in C and E to a new class F and let C and E inherit from F. In most cases it is called Mixin. Look at this answer for more explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/547714/3421655.