# Idiomatic multiple inheritance with python Abstract Base Classes

Tags: python, oop, interface, subclass, abc

In simplest terms what I want is a `tuple` with one or two additional methods. `__new__` or `__init__` are not going to be modified.

I would like to create an abstract base class that is subclass of `collections.abc.Sequence`. Then I want to use it for what is basically a `tuple` subclass. The class diagram is something like:

```
   collections.abc.Sequence
          /       \
         /         \
        /           \
      MyABC       tuple
        \           /
         \         /
          \       /
           MyClass
```

Reasons:

- `MyABC` defines some custom interfaces. It is there so third parties are not forced to subclass `MyClass`.
- `tuple` is needed for its performance and the already implemented methods.

Questions:

- Is the idiomatic way just to write `class MyClass(MyABC, tuple)` or should I play with the registers?
- Are there any other obvious problems that I am missing?
- Will the space and performance benefits of `tuple` be lost because of the subclassing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Is the idiomatic way just to write class MyClass(MyABC, tuple) or should I play with the registers?

  It looks to me like a quite idiomatic way of doing this. This is also what is called an "[inheritance diamond](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033903/python-super-method-and-calling-alternatives)".
  The `__init__` method for `MyClass` could look like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033903/python-super-method-and-calling-alternatives).
- Are there any other obvious problems that I am missing?

  Well, it depends on some aspects which are not quite specified in the question, like 
  what do you exactly want to do? How are you doing it? How is the usage pattern of this new subclass? How general/specific are the new methods you have in your new class? There is a more efficient/cleaner/readable/easier/whatever way of doing this without creating a subclass? And even if yes, is it still worth doing, if you will gain more flexibility/readability and so?

  As a general rule, I would say that it's not only ok, but also desirable to create subclasses
  if you will use it often enough and/or it will enable you to solve some problem more easily without
  drastic/highly undesirable collateral effects.
- Will the space and performance benefits of tuple be lost because of the subclassing?

  That's a tricky question. Again, depending on what you are doing and how you design your subclass etc..., possibly.
  Remember, for example, that tuples are an immutable type and this property has some performance advantages
  over mutable types. So, if you e.g. would somehow modify this property, this could represent some loss, compared
  to the original tuple. I'm also not quite sure how Python will see a subclass of a tuple. By that I mean,
  I don't know if Python would still 'blindly believe' your class is immutable and so still behave exactly like a tuple.
  And if not, how bad it would actually be in your specific case. The immutable/mutable issue is simply an example, other even more relevant issues might exist, but I couldn't really say for sure...
  Maybe you could do some small-scale test to measure the performance.

Considering some of [these](http://python-history.blogspot.de/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html) aspects (By Guido himself) could also be a good idea.

I hope this helps!