# How to extend inherited method by using original in python

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I'm trying to extend the functionality of a class method in python, but i don't know exactly how. Here are an example of (obvious wrong) python code witch maybe explains what i want to do:

```
class A(object):
    def foo(self):
        return dict({'field1':'value1'})

class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        return A.foo().update({'field2':'value2'})
```

The extension of `foo` in `B` should return both fields, `A` and B`.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `dict.update` method updates the `dict` but returns `None`. So you need to be careful to return the dict, not the value (None) returned by `update`.

In this case, you can "extend" the `foo` method using 
`super(B, self).foo()` or `A.foo(self)`:

```
class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        dct = super(B, self).foo()
        dct.update({'field2':'value2'})
        return dct
```

The [purpose of `super`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5034440/190597) is to resolve inheritance diamonds (which arise due to multiple inheritance). [Using super](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) leaves open the possibility that your `B` can be incorporated into a class structure that uses multiple inheritance. [There are pitfalls](http://fuhm.org/super-harmful/) to using super however. If you wish for your class to support single inheritance only, then

```
dct = super(B, self).foo()
```

can be replaced by

```
dct = A.foo(self)
```

There are many reasons why one might wish to avoid using multiple inheritance ([1](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=246341), [2](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=246483), [3](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=254367), [4](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=254507)). If those reasons apply to your situation, there is nothing wrong with -- and in fact strong reasons for -- using the simpler, more direct

```
dct = A.foo(self)
```

instead of `super`.