# Python: How to successfully inherit Sqlite3.Cursor and add my customized method

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to make my own MagicCursor class. I want it to inherit all method and attributes from sqlite3.Cursor(). But it looks not that easy in t his case.

usually we create a cursor like this:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
crs = conn.cursor()
```

because there's a connection in between. So I think I have to define my own Connection Class and then define my own Cursor.

Here's what I want to implement:

```
import sqlite3
conn = MyConnect('test.db') ## this returns me a connect object, inherit from         sqlite3.Connection 
crs = conn.cursor() ## this returns me a MyCursor class,
                ## which inherit from sqlite3.Cursor() and has my customized method
```

Here's my code, but failed.

```
class MyConnect(sqlite3.Connection):
    def cursor(self):
        return MyCursor(self)

class MyCursor(sqlite3.cursor):
    def __init__(self, connect):
        self = connect.cursor()

    def mymethod1(self, argv)
         ...... return ...... ## what ever I defined
```

Anyone got an idea how to implement that?

Comment: I do not believe you want to reassign `self` like you do in your `__init__` method.  Shouldn't that be `sqlite3.cursor.__init__(self)` (or something close)?  Sqlite3 is a compiled extension on my system - you'd have to look up the call signature and see how (or if) it supports a connection parameter.  You may not be able to go about adding a method to a compiled extension in this way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import sqlite3
class MyConnect(sqlite3.Connection):
    def cursor(self):
        return super(MyConnect, self).cursor(MyCursor)

class MyCursor(sqlite3.Cursor):
    def mymethod1(self, argv):
        print('Got here')

conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:', factory=MyConnect)
print(conn)
# <__main__.MyConnect object at 0x90db66c>

cursor = conn.cursor()
print(cursor)
# <__main__.MyCursor object at 0x90d19dc>

cursor.mymethod1('foo')
# Got here
```

In this example, `super(MyConnect, self).cursor(MyCursor)` calls
`sqlite3.Connection.cursor(MyCursor)`.

[sqlite3.Connection.cursor](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.cursor) accepts an optional argument, `cursorClass`. When supplied, that is the class used to instantiate the cursor.

Comment: It works!! Thank you!! Could you tell me how could this works?

Comment: [super](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) calls the cursor method of (roughly speaking) a parent class of MyConnect. In this case, `sqlite3.Connection.cursor`.

Comment: More accurately, `super(MyConnect, self).cursor()` calls the cursor method of the next class in `MyConnect`'s MRO after `type(self)`. That [may or may not be a parent class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5033903/190597) of `MyConnect`.