# python super() - two argument version in context of __new__

Tags: python

I've read [the documentation for `super()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) multiple times but I still don't get what the two argument version **returns**.

> Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or
>   sibling class of *type*. This is useful for accessing inherited methods
>   that have been overridden in a class.

1. What is a proxy object?
2. parent **or sibling**?

> If the second argument is an object, `isinstance(obj, type)` must be
>   true. If the second argument is a type, `issubclass(type2, type)` must
>   be true (this is useful for classmethods).

3. That's all nice but **what is returned**? And what does the syntax `super(a,b)` **mean**?

In context of [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__),

> Typical implementations create a new instance of the class by invoking
>   the superclass’s __new__() method using `super(currentclass,
>   cls).__new__(cls[, ...])` with appropriate arguments and then modifying
>   the newly-created instance as necessary before returning it.

`super(currentclass, cls).__new__(cls[, ...])`

If `currentclass` is equal to `cls`, you have `super(currentclass, currentclass)`

4. What does that return? What does that syntax mean?
5. How does this statement return an instance of `cls` so that `__init__` will be called on the returned object?

Comment: The syntax `super(a,b)` means: call the `super` function with two arguments, `a` and `b`.

Comment: A proxy object is an object that forwards method calls to another object.

Comment: 1) See melpomene comment. 2) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27954695/what-is-a-sibling-class-in-python. 3) I cannot understand your third question, you just wrote the constraints above (`instance(b, a)`)? 4) What is returned by `__new__` is explain in the link you posted.

Comment: @Holt what does `super(class1, class2)` return?

Comment: @melpomene I know what a function call is. I meant what is the relation of `a` to `b`. What constraints do there have to be.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to "what does `super` return" isn't anything like "it returns a list" or "it returns a modified copy of the second object". `super` returns an object of type `super`, a type designed specifically to have the qualities the documentation says it has.

Perhaps it would help to show a pure-Python implementation of `super`. If `super` wasn't written in C, it would look basically like this:

```
class super(object):
    def __init__(self, klass, object_or_klass):
        # The real super can be called with 0 arguments on Python 3,
        # but digging into the magic that makes that work isn't relevant here.

        if isinstance(object_or_klass, klass):
            mro = type(object_or_klass).__mro__
            self.obj_type = type(object_or_klass)
            self.obj = object_or_klass
        elif issubclass(object_or_klass, klass):
            mro = object_or_klass.__mro__
            self.obj_type = object_or_klass
            self.obj = None
        else:
            raise TypeError

        # Set up a copy of the MRO to search,
        # with everything up to and including klass skipped
        self.searchlist = mro[mro.index(klass)+1:]

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        # self.searchlist would be infinite recursion, as would super().__getattribute__
        searchlist = object.__getattribute__(self, 'searchlist')

        # Search the method resolution order for the attribute we want.
        for klass in searchlist:
            if name in klass.__dict__:
                attr = klass.__dict__[name]
                break
        else:
            raise AttributeError

        if hasattr(attr, '__get__'):
            # Handle descriptors.
            obj = object.__getattribute__(self, 'obj')
            obj_type = object.__getattribute__(self, 'obj_type')
            attr = attr.__get__(obj, obj_type)
        return attr
```

Now you can see that `super(a, b)` constructs a `super` object, and `super(a, b).whatever` calls the `__getattribute__` method of that `super` object to search the method resolution order of the second argument for the attribute we want. The attribute lookup procedure for `b.whatever` is very similar, just without chopping off the first part of the MRO, and checking the instance dict if `b` isn't a class.

Comment: [This is the `super` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super). Why doesn't it tell what `super(class1, class2)` do?

Comment: @Adrian: It says what `super(class1, class2)` does in about as much detail as it says what `super(klass, obj)` does. It just needs more detail about the lookup it implements in general, and perhaps a link to [how the MRO works](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/).

Answer (score -1):

You should *definitely* watch Raymond Hettinger's talk from PyCon 2015, [Super is considered super!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo)

But if not, why not add a bunch of print statements to answer your questions?

```
# (object) is only required in Python2
class Mom(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('Mom is initializing - args: {!r} kwargs: {!r}'.format(
              args, kwargs))

    def do_something(self):
        print('Doing some Mom thing')


class Dad(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('Dad is initializing - args: {!r} kwargs: {!r}'.format(
              args, kwargs))

    def do_something(self):
        print('Doing some Dad thing')


class Sister(Mom, Dad):
    def __init__(self, name):
        print('initializing a Sister with name: {!r}'.format(name))
        parent = super(Sister, self)
        print(type(parent))
        print(parent)
        print('Calling super __init__')
        parent.__init__(name)

    def do_something(self, value):
        if value == 5:
            print('calling method on super')
            super(Sister, self).do_something()
        else:
            print('Sister did something')


class Brother(Mom):
    def __init__(self, name):
        print('initializing a Brother with name: {!r}'.format(name))
        parent = super(Brother, self)
        print(type(parent))
        print(parent)
        print('Calling super __init__')
        parent.__init__(name)

    def do_something(self, value):
        if value == 5:
            print('calling method on super')
            super(Brother, self).do_something()
        else:
            print('Brother did something')


b = Brother('Bear')
s = Sister('Moon')

b.do_something(3)
b.do_something(5)

s.do_something(3)
s.do_something(5)
```

That produces the following output (with added commentary):

```
<type 'super'>
<super: <class 'Brother'>, <Brother object>>
Calling super __init__
Mom is initializing - args: ('Bear',) kwargs: {}
```

Apparently, `super` returns a class of type `super`. Which, according to the documentation, is a proxy object. A proxy, by definition, is a replacement for something else. In this case, the proxy is a replacement for getting `Mom`. You can see that when we actually call the `__init__` function, that Mom's init function is called.

```
initializing a Sister with name: 'Moon'
<type 'super'>
<super: <class 'Sister'>, <Sister object>>
Calling super __init__
Mom is initializing - args: ('Moon',) kwargs: {}
```

You'll notice here, that Dad's init function isn't called. That's because, if you watch Raymond's talk, you'll know that `super` looks for the function on parents from left to right.

```
Brother did something
calling method on super
Doing some Mom thing
```

You see the same behavior repeated here

```
Sister did something
calling method on super
Doing some Mom thing
```

If you change the order on Sister, to `Dad, Mom`, you'll see that those calls change:

```
initializing a Brother with name: 'Bear'
<type 'super'>
<super: <class 'Brother'>, <Brother object>>
Calling super __init__
Mom is initializing - args: ('Bear',) kwargs: {}
initializing a Sister with name: 'Moon'
<type 'super'>
<super: <class 'Sister'>, <Sister object>>
Calling super __init__
Dad is initializing - args: ('Moon',) kwargs: {}
Brother did something
calling method on super
Doing some Mom thing
Sister did something
calling method on super
Doing some Dad thing
```

To sum up:

1. A proxy is something that stands in for something else. In our case, `super` is a proxy for both Mom & Dad, depending on which order they're inherited from.
2. Honestly, I couldn't get any kind of meaningful sibling thing to work. I'm not sure when you'd even need that anyway.
3. An instance of `super` is returned.
4. That would really only work if you had something that inherited from `type`, e.g. `super(type, type)`, because you need an *instance* of that type. `object` would also work because:

   print(isinstance(object, object))
   print(isinstance(type, type))
   print(isinstance(object, type))
   print(isinstance(type, object))

There's some pretty involved magic going on around *that* process.

5. Are you asking how functions return things? Because **new** is a function - and it returns or it doesn't. `object.__new__` returns something. I'm not sure where the actual source code is for that function, or I could point you there if you were interested in the exact mechanism.