# python __new__ - must return an instance of cls

Tags: python, super, python-internals

[According to the docs,](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__)

> Typical implementations create a new instance of the class by invoking
>   the superclass’s `__new__()` method using `super(currentclass,
>   cls).__new__(cls[, ...])` with appropriate arguments and then modifying
>   the newly-created instance as necessary before returning it. 
>   ...
>
> If `__new__` does not return an instance of cls, then the new
>   instance’s `__init__()` method will not be invoked.

The [simplest implementation of `__new__`:](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__)

```
class MyClass:
    def __new__(cls):
        RetVal = super(currentclass, cls).__new__(cls)
        return RetVal
```

How exactly does `super(currentclass, cls).__new__(cls[, ...])` return an object of type `cls`?

That statement calls `object.__new__(cls)` where `cls` is `MyClass`.

So how would class `object` know how to create the type `MyClass`?

Comment: You *told* it what type the returned object should have. That's what the `cls` parameter is for.

Comment: @user2357112 I don't get your answer. The return type it expects is `cls`. How does `super(currentclass, cls).__new__(cls)` return a `cls`? Are you saying it implicitly casts it?

Comment: `object.__new__` looks at the `cls` parameter you passed it and says, "Gee, I guess Adrian wants an object of type `cls`. I should make one of those."

Comment: @user2357112 Ok. What about the `super(class1, class2)` statement; what's the logic there? It gets the base class that's common to both classes or what?

Comment: [Didn't I just answer that for you a few hours ago?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38661438/python-super-two-argument-version-in-context-of-new)

Comment: @user2357112 Is this correct? ["To begin with super() in itself is simply shorthand for super(A, B), where A is the class wherein the code occurs, and B is the first argument to the function in which the code occurs; so in your particular case](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9092004/4784683) If that's correct, seems pointless; doesn't Python know in which function the code is?

Comment: Does it matter how Python does this? `object.__new__` returns a new C structure that links to the class object. It is all done in C. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @MartijnPieters the `object.__new__` answer absolutely makes sense and yes that's what I'm looking for. What I'd also like to know is the syntax behind `super`. In the doc, says in `super(class1, class2)` that `issubclass(class2, class1)` must be true. OK. But then how does `super` use BOTH classes to return whatever it returns?

Comment: @Adrian: that's an entirely different question; I have written [several answers about `super()` that cover this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A100297+super+self+class+type) and more.

Comment: @Adrian: it matters what *class* the function was original defined on, vis-a-vis the MRO. The 'magic' `__class__` closure defines this. Also see [Why is Python 3.x's super() magic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19608134)

Answer (score 2):

`super(MyClass, cls).__new__(cls)` first searches the MRO (method resolution order) of the `cls` object (skipping past `MyClass` in that sequence), until it finds an object with a `__new__` attribute.

In your case, that is `object.__new__`:

```
>>> class MyClass:
...     def __new__(cls):
...         RetVal = super(MyClass, cls).__new__(cls)
...         return RetVal
...
>>> MyClass.__mro__
(<class '__main__.MyClass'>, <class 'object'>)
>>> hasattr(MyClass.__mro__[1], '__new__')
True
```

but if you subclassed `MyClass` and mixed in another class into the MRO with a `__new__` method then it *could* be another method.

`object.__new__` is implemented in C, see the [`object_new()` function](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.1/Objects/typeobject.c#l3405); it contains a hook for abstract base classes to make sure you are not trying to instantiate an abstract class, then delegates to the `tp_alloc` slot, which usually will be set to [`PyType_GenericAlloc`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.1/Objects/typeobject.c#l933), which adds a new `PyObject` struct to the heap. It is that struct that represents the instance to the interpreter.

Comment: Shouldn't `currentclass` be replaced by `MyClass`?

Comment: @Adrian: I was following your example in your question. Yes, a correct invocation would use `MyClass`.

Comment: Ok. So then can you point to **documentation** that explains what `super(MyClass, cls)` **means** i.e. how does `super` act on its two arguments to return . . . whatever it returns. [Python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) does NOT state this info.

Comment: @Adrian: then I don't know what to point you to. That documentation is spot on.

Comment: Where in that link is my question answered: how do the two arguments to super influence/affect what is returned? It just says that the second argument must be a subclass of the first argument.

Comment: @Adrian: `super(type)` returns an unbound proxy, `super(type, object-or-type)` produces bound attributes. The proxy uses attribute access to search the MRO in the same way `getattr()` does, skipping `type` in that order.

Comment: @Adrian: the documentation makes assumptions about you knowing what MRO is, and what binding does. Also see [How can I use super() with one argument in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30190185) where I dive into what binding means and how the one-argument from can be bound after-the-fact.

Comment: what does bound mean in this case? In my example: super(MyClass, cls) what is bound to what and what does "bound" mean?

Comment: ok I'll read about mro and binding. Thanks for taking the time

Comment: @Adrian: also see the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html); binding is what happens when you look up attributes on an instance or class that implement that protocol. It is how methods acquire the `self` argument and how `property` objects end up calling a function when accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Few things, first of all you need to write explicit inheritance from `object` like this:

```
class MyClass(object):
```

You should read about [old classes and new classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/what-is-the-difference-between-old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python) on python(only on python 2, in python 3 it does not matter)

For your question, I think you missed the point or syntax of `super()` functions. Again, small change to your code:

```
RetVal = super(MyClass, cls).__new__(cls)
```

In this way you reference to the parent-class by using `super(MyClass, cls)` and calling a method from this parent-class **new**(of course you can use any other method)

**edit**
After reading your comments, I'll just add that `super()` doesn't have to take any arguments in Python 3 so maybe it's more trivial for you.  Highly recommended to read more about the `super()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods)

Comment: I understand the intended effects. I don't get what passing `cls` to `super` **in addition to** `MyClass` does.

Comment: I know that `issubclass(class2, class1)` must be true but why does `super` need `cls` to return whatever it returns?

Comment: That's a question about `super()`, not about `__new__()`.

Comment: @Adrian I added links so you can read more about it, it's different question and should be answer on different thread.